# Can't see home Wifi (up and working) after changing wireless network name

Tags: release-loki, wifi

I changed the *Wireless Network Name* in my router and the channel from 3 to 13. The Wifi works perfectly since I can connect via my cellphone (using the new name)

In Loki I can't even see my connection, when I could connect without issues when it had its previous name.

I can see lots of other Wifi signals, just not mine (neither the old nor the new one)

How can I fix/debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

This is an issue with the wireless driver apparently ([How to use Wi-Fi channels above 11?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59310/how-to-use-wi-fi-channels-above-11)) where higher channels (above 7) are not detected.

Changing the channel to 7 restored the visibility of my router in my laptop.